# iOS 17 interactive widgets - remove button background and padding

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit, ios17

I'm trying to create new iOS 17 interactive widget. To be able to add "action" I want to use new [`init(_:intent:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Button/init(_:intent:)-7urde?changes=___2) initializer of `Button` which allow me to perform given intent when button gets pressed.

The problem is, my button is supposed to be just the green inner rectangle with the smile image, but system adds its own background with padding. Is there any way to remove it?

Example code:

```
Button(intent: MyIntent()) {
    MyLabel()
}
```

How it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I figured out that I have to set button's style to `PlainButtonStyle`. Now the background and the padding is removed.

```
Button(intent: MyIntent()) {
    MyLabel()
}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think I might try this technique to solve this related problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345502/ios17-interactive-widget-how-to-change-background-color-of-button-with-custom

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a custom style or perform a custom animation when the button is pressed you can do something like this:

```
private struct MoveUpButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var resizeScale: CGFloat
    var offset: CGPoint

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? resizeScale : 1.0)
            .offset(x: configuration.isPressed ? offset.x : 0, y: configuration.isPressed ? offset.y : 0)
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
.buttonStyle(MoveUpButtonStyle(resizeScale: 2.0, offset: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -40)))
```