# iOS 17 Interactive Widget - How to change background color of Button with Custom Label view, in SwiftUI widget?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Currently, I have the following SwiftUI widget.

```
struct TodoWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    let todoItems: [TodoItem] = DataManager().todoItems
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
            ForEach(0..<todoItems.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Button(intent: TodoIntent(item: todoItems[index].taskName)) {
                    Label(todoItems[index].taskName, systemImage: "circle\(todoItems[index].isCompleted ? ".fill" : "")")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading).lineLimit(1)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.black) // label color
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }.background(SwiftUI.Color.fromInt(0xfff7ce46)) // yellow color
    }
}
```

It looks as following

[image]

What I am expecting, is using semi-transparent white background for the interactive button.

I wish it will look similar to this main app screen, implemented in UIKit's `UICollectionViewCell`.

[image]

The round-cornered, semi-transparent background is implemented using the following code

```
contextView.layer.cornerRadius = 22
contextView.layer.masksToBounds = true
contextView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
```

---

I change the SwiftUI code to

```
struct TodoWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    let todoItems: [TodoItem] = DataManager().todoItems
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
            ForEach(0..<todoItems.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Button(intent: TodoIntent(item: todoItems[index].taskName)) {
                    Label(todoItems[index].taskName, systemImage: "circle\(todoItems[index].isCompleted ? ".fill" : "")")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading).lineLimit(1)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.black)    // label color
                .background(SwiftUI.Color.fromInt(0x7fffffff))   // semi-transparent white color
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }.background(SwiftUI.Color.fromInt(0xfff7ce46)) // yellow color
    }
}
```

---

However, I am not getting the desired result.

[image]

---

May I know, how to change background color of Button with Custom Label view, in SwiftUI widget?

Comment: See this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050707/ios-17-interactive-widgets-remove-button-background-and-padding/77442016#77442016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of the default button style. You should use `.buttonStyle(.plain)` on the button:

```
Button(intent: TodoIntent(item: todoItems[index].taskName)) {
    Label(todoItems[index].taskName, systemImage: "circle\(todoItems[index].isCompleted ? ".fill" : "")")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading).lineLimit(1)
}
.foregroundColor(.black) // label color
.buttonStyle(.plain) //  Here
```

---

###### Not related but worth to mention

You can also refactor the button like:

```
let item = todoItems[index]
Button(
    item.taskName,
    systemImage: "circle\(item.isCompleted ? ".fill" : "")",
    intent: TodoIntent(item: item.taskName)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using an extension to `Color` which is the static function `fromInt`.

My guess is that this is not working as you expect.

Try replacing these function calls with conventional color definitions:

- Instead of `.background(SwiftUI.Color.fromInt(0x7fffffff))`, try using `.background(.white.opacity(0.5))` or `.background(Color(white: 1, opacity: 0.5))`.
- Instead of `.background(SwiftUI.Color.fromInt(0xfff7ce46))`, try using `.background(.yellow)`.